# Displaying Owner Information of Sim card Android

Tags: android

I am writing a Small Android Application, which displays all the details in the sim card. I found out how to display info like IMEI, Network Operator Name etc from [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

I just wanted to know whether it is possible to display the Sim Card Holder's Name in Android application? Is that information stored in the sim card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim card doesn't hold such information about owner. SIM card holds following information.

- Text Messages
- Phone Contacts
- Last number called with time/date
- security data
- billing information

Resources

- http://www.ehow.com/facts_7291974_information-stored-sim-card_.html
- http://www.imore.com/tipb-answers-sim-card
- http://cellularforensics.blogspot.in/2009/03/what-does-sim-card-hold.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is, which I doubt, then it is likely to be wrong since sim cards and phones get moved around between people and the telephone operator often doesn't get told.

Comment: But while buying it will be registered to a single person which will be stored in the sim card(?? not sure) Is it possible to fetch that information?

Comment: Not necessarily true - it depends on the country - not every country insists that a person is registered as owning a sim card.